# How to use diffExcludeObjects config to ignore all columns ending with id in all tables?

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I want to ignore all columns that end with "_id" in all tables using liquibase maven plugin's diff command. When I run it using this config `diffExcludeObjects=table:position, column:.*._id` the diff ignores the columns in position that end with _id as expected.

However, when I try to change the config to hit every table `diffExcludeObjects=table:.*., column:.*._id` that ignores all fields in all tables which is not what I want.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The values passed in to `diffExcludeObjects` and the like are treated as Java Pattern objects (i.e. regular expressions), so the pattern `.*.` matches things that have 0 or more repetitions of any character, followed by any character. It seems like that should match most table names, so I am not sure why it isn't working as expected.

You could try simplifying the pattern to just `.*` to see if that has the desired effect.

Comment: hey Steve, do you know if matching a column will exclude the entire object or just the columns matched?

as of right now, if i specify a specific column to match in a table the entire table gets excluded when the diff is executed

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head. I'm going to have to set up a repro case and run it in a debugger so I can learn how it all works.